# How can you set the gravity value for the LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor on android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, inertial-navigation

I am developing an  app for the Samsung Galaxy S4. I am trying to use the LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor which uses sensor fusion with the accelerometer and gyroscope to subtract gravity so you can get a clean value for acceleration. It works pretty well, but I noticed that for whichever axis is pointed downward, a value of about 0.5 m/s/s is shown constantly. I also notice that when I use the ACCELEROMETER sensor, the gravity reading is about 9.2-9.3 m/s/s.

Is there some way that I can adjust the gravity constant that the LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor uses, or a way to calibrate the accelerometer itself to display the true value for gravity?

Thanks to anyone who helps, I really need it.

Comment: Are you sure `LINEAR_ACCELERATION` uses fused sensors? According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) page, it just gets rid of gravity from the `ACCELERATION` sensor (most likely through the high-pass filter on the page). Edit: Never mind. Addressed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/GOm9yhTFZaM/eaoNuQEMAb4J).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still need help calibrating the value used for gravity, or calibrating the accelerometer.

Comment: Someone please help!!!